# Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 desktop and desktop icons show through application window

Tags: gnome, 17.04

Strange problem that's been occurring for a couple of months now... probably due to a system software update... my guess.

All application windows now have an approximately 1 pixel line where the desktop shows through, and desktop icons are visible.

Here's a screenshot that shows the problem...

[image]

Any ideas why?

Comment: What happens if you change the GTK+ theme?

Comment: @pomsky  Good guess. I used `Tweak Tool` to change the GTK+ theme... both Radiance (my default), and Ambiance, fail the same way. However, Adwaita (the default) works! You would think that Ambiance/Radiance, which are standard Unity themes, would work, wouldn't you? Do you think a recent system software update could have caused this problem? Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Not sure whether it will help, but you may try reinstalling `light-themes`. Worth a shot.

Comment: @pomsky I did reinstall `light-themes` and reset my GTK+ theme to Radiance, and the problem was still there. So... back to Adwaita! Thanks for the followup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be a theme problem!

Either of the Unity themes, Ambiance or Radiance, would show the problem.

Choosing the default GNOME theme, Adwaita, solved the problem!