# Windows have non-rounded white borders

Tags: gnome

I recently updated from unity to gde3. So far everything seems to be working, except for one minor annoyance. The terminal and all of the windows have, in the top left and right corners, non-rounded white borders.

[image: whiteborder]

Any suggestions on where to look / what to change to fix that are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a GTK+ theming issue. The Ubuntu themes (viz. Ambiance and Radiance) sometimes exhibit glitches like this in a GNOME session (here's [another issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961691/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-desktop-and-desktop-icons-show-through-application-window)).

As a workaround you may switch to another GTK+ theme, for example *Adwaita*, the GNOME default. To do that follow the steps below.

1. Open *GNOME Tweak Tool* (if it's not installed you may install it by running `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`).
2. In the **Appearance** section select "Adwaita *(default)*" in the box next to **GTK+**.
   [image]

You may try using other themes, [gnome-look.org](https://www.gnome-look.org/) is a good source to find themes.